# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native/Libraries/Image/resolveAssetSource'

Tags: react-native, npm, webpack

I'm adding an audio module in my current react-native project. I have tried installing several modules ([react-native-sound](https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound), [react-native-track-player](https://github.com/react-native-kit/react-native-track-player)). Getting in both modules the same Error output, which is always pointing in the **'react-native/Libraries/Image/resolveAssetsource'** as module not found.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native-track-player/lib/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native/Libraries/Image/resolveAssetsource' in 'D:\workspaces\web\react\blink\node_modules\react-native-track-player\lib'
 @ ./node_modules/react-native-track-player/lib/index.js 1:401-459
 @ ./node_modules/react-native-track-player/index.js
 @ ./components/ui/BlinkAudio/BlinkAudio.web.js
 @ ./components/ui/BlinkAudio/index.web.js
 @ ./components/dialogs/ResourceDetails/ResourceDetails.js
 @ ./components/dialogs/ResourceDetails/index.js
 @ ./components/panels/catalog/CatalogPanel.js
 @ ./components/parts/Main/Main.js
 @ ./components/parts/Main/index.js
 @ ./index.web.js
```

This is the current imports in the index file of the audio module react-native-track-player:

```
import { Platform, AppRegistry, DeviceEventEmitter, NativeEventEmitter, NativeModules } from 'react-native';
import resolveAssetSource from 'react-native/Libraries/Image/resolveAssetsource';
```

I have tried to fix this including 'resolveAssetsource' from the imports of 'react-native' as below:

```
import { 
    Platform, 
    AppRegistry, 
    DeviceEventEmitter, 
    NativeEventEmitter, 
    NativeModules, 
    resolveAssetsource 
} from 'react-native';
```

But I am not pretty sure if it would be the best way and normally I don't like to touch package node-modules directly.

I also tried to exclude the audio module from webpack loaders with no result.

```
 module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: function (modulePath) {
          return (
            /node_modules/.test(modulePath) &&
            !/node_modules(\\|\/)react-native-track-player/.test(modulePath)
          );
        },
```

I wonder if someone could help me to find an answer and if is possible to deal with this react-native issue, as I'm thinking that these audio modules are calling wrongly the resolveAssetsource, or in the other hand, react-native doesn't provide this specific Library for third parties, I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a syntax error issue. There is no file nor module named `resolveAsset`**`s`**`ource`, the module and filename is `resolveAsset`**`S`**`ource` with a capital `S`.

Try to remove `react-native-track-player` with `yarn remove react-native-track-player` and install it again (*or delete the entire `node_modules` directory and run `yarn install` again*) as the source code under [`react-native-track-player/lib/index.js`](https://github.com/react-native-kit/react-native-track-player/blob/dev/lib/index.js) has it properly without any errors:

```js
import { Platform, AppRegistry, DeviceEventEmitter, NativeEventEmitter, NativeModules } from 'react-native';
import resolveAssetSource from 'react-native/Libraries/Image/resolveAssetSource';
```

If you use it elsewhere, you'll have to import it like this:

```js
import resolveAssetSource from 'react-native/Libraries/Image/resolveAssetSource';
```

But that is not the prefered way to do it, as this method is a member of the RN `Image` class/component [`Image.resolveAssetSource(source)`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#resolveassetsource), so, it's better to just import the `Image` component and use it like this:

```js
import { 
    Platform, 
    AppRegistry, 
    DeviceEventEmitter, 
    NativeEventEmitter, 
    NativeModules, 
    Image  // Add Image import
} from 'react-native';

// and use the function as of Image method

let audioAssetSource = Image.resolveAssetSource(audioSource);
```

Either way, you'll have the method working and resolve the asset source information.